# Can't access remote tomcat webapps

Tags: linux, tomcat

I've got tomcat running on a remote Linux box. We have one web app running on it okay, 
`/project1` (not root), with a "project1.war" auto deployed. I've now uploaded "project2.war" and I can see it's been extracted etc., but when I go to `mysite/project2` I get a "not found" error.

I can't for the life of me see any references in server.xml, context.xml, web.xml for project1 to map its URL, so I'm really at a loss for how I'm supposed to get /project2 seeable. I'm very new to Linux, looking for some advice. Here's my server.xml entry:

```
<Host name="mysite.co.nz"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
            xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">
</Host>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have to add it to apache 2 sites-available list